# A generic stored procedure that can take any source table name as a parameter and merge to a target table

Tags: sql-server

This is my code.

```
Create Procedure Merge_tables 
     @tablename varchar(20)
As
    create table temp1 ( column_name varchar(20) )

    insert into temp1 (column_name)
        select Column_Name 
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        where TABLE_NAME = 'result'

        intersect

        select Column_Name 
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        where TABLE_NAME = '@tablename'

    Declare @name varchar(max)
    Declare @concat varchar(max)

    set @concat = ''

    while (select COUNT(*) from temp1)>0
    Begin 
        set @name = (select top 1 * from temp1)
        set @concat = @concat + @name + ','

        select @concat as combined

        delete temp1 where temp1.column_name = @name
    End

    Merge result as T 
    using @tablename as S on T.TXN_KEY = S.TXN_KEY 

    when not matched then 
       insert ('+@concat+') values ('+@concat+') 
    when matched then 
       update set T.TXN_KEY = S.TXN_KEY(?)
```

Table temp1 is storing the common column names. Only specific thing is the key to be matched upon which is TXN_KEY. Rest everything else is generic. Towards the end of the while loop @concat has the combined column names separated by a comma.

The error I get in the merge statement is:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   Invalid column name '+@concat+'

Also, for update statement to work `@concat` string needs to be split to set values for individual columns. I have been trying to crack this for a while now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok you have to pass your target table and source table, to define Primary keys.  This works, I have tested it a lot.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Merge_Tables
(
    @tablenameTarget VARCHAR(128),
    @tablenameSource VARCHAR(128)
)

AS

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SET NOCOUNT ON

--variables
DECLARE @targetPK VARCHAR(128),
    @sourcePK VARCHAR(128),
    @columns VARCHAR(MAX),

    @sql VARCHAR(8000)


--temp table for the primary keys
CREATE TABLE #tableMapping
(
    TargetPK VARCHAR(128),
    SourcePK VARCHAR(128),
    Columns VARCHAR(MAX)
)

--temp table for the comma delimted columns
CREATE TABLE #Columns 
(
    ColumnsUpdate VARCHAR(MAX)
)


--get the primary keys for both target and source tables.  so we make sure we dont update or insert them
INSERT INTO #tableMapping
SELECT cu.COLUMN_NAME, 
    sourcePK.COLUMN_NAME,
    data.columns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS ta
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu 
    ON cu.Constraint_name = ta.CONSTRAINT_NAME
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT cus.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tas
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cus 
        ON cus.Constraint_name = ta.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    WHERE tas.Table_Name = @tablenameSource
        AND ta.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'Primary Key'
) AS sourcePK
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ',' + Column_Name 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns Columns
                WHERE ta.Table_Name = Columns.Table_Name
                    AND Columns.Column_Name <> cu.COLUMN_NAME --dont get the primary key 
                ORDER BY Column_Name
                FOR XML PATH ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') columns

) AS data
WHERE ta.Table_Name = @tablenameTarget
    AND ta.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'Primary Key'

--populate the variables so we can use it in our dynamic merge statement
SELECT @targetPK = TargetPK,
    @sourcePK = SourcePK,
    @columns = Columns 
FROM #tableMapping


--make sure the rows match from the source and target tables, and make it in a comma delimted string
INSERT INTO #Columns
SELECT
    STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ',' + 'TRGT.' + Column_Name + ' = SRCE.' + COLUMN_NAME
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns Columns
                WHERE t.Table_Name = Columns.Table_Name
                    AND Column_Name <> @targetPK
                ORDER BY Column_Name
                FOR XML PATH ('')
             ), 1, 1, ''
    )Columns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns t
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS ta
    ON ta.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu 
    ON ccu.Constraint_name = ta.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE t.Table_Name = '' + @tablenameTarget + ''

INTERSECT 

SELECT
    STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ',' + 'TRGT.' + Column_Name + ' = SRCE.' + COLUMN_NAME
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns Columns
                WHERE t.Table_Name = Columns.Table_Name
                    AND Column_Name <> @sourcePK
                ORDER BY Column_Name
                FOR XML PATH ('')
             ), 1, 1, ''
    )Columns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns t
WHERE t.Table_Name = '' + @tablenameSource + ''



--use dynamic sql for our merge statement
SET @sql = 'MERGE ' + @tablenameTarget + ' AS TRGT
            USING ' + @tablenameSource + ' AS SRCE
                ON SRCE.' + @sourcePK + ' = TRGT.' + @targetPK + '
            WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ' + (SELECT ColumnsUpdate FROM #Columns)+ '
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
                    INSERT (' + (SELECT  @Columns)+ ')
                    VALUES (' + (SELECT 'SRCE.' + REPLACE(@columns, ',',',SRCE.')) + ')
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
                    DELETE;'

EXEC (@sql) 

DROP TABLE #Columns
DROP TABLE #tableMapping
```

Comment: wow..thanks a ton.this is indeed a big one...not in front of my PC now..will let you know how this goes..I guess I will have to read up on STUFF and FOR XML..

Comment: Not able to test it over the weekend as I dont have the execution privilege. Should get that on Monday. Will definitely let you know how it goes.

Comment: it seems like the procedure executes fine but it is not inserting or updating anything. hope to hear back from you soon..

Comment: oh wow ok kwl.  Do me a favour create 2 tables. Test1 and Test2. Both with a Primary Key. and a Name column.  Then In Test2(Source table) insert your name in the Name column.  then execute the SP Merge_Tables 'Test1', 'Test2'. And let me know what you get

Comment: Procedure ran fine but no data inserted in test1.

Comment: Even when the procedure is ran with test1 and test2 passed without the quotes it runs fine. Execute Merge_Tables test1,test2
Command(s) completed successfully.

Comment: Ok let me test again

Comment: exec Merge_Tables 'Test1', 'Test2'

Comment: Ok it only works if both tables have Primary Keys. But thats what I expect.

Comment: even I am making sure that both have primary keys...but no luck..can you doublecheck then whe you pasted the code here..no typos were made?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115136/discussion-between-vishal-bhatt-and-mvisser).

Comment: in the example for test1 and test2 is your primary key name? or something else?

Comment: mine took very quick. it doesn't matter what the Primary key name is.  It will search each table for the Primary Key.  Can you pass me the CREATE scripts for Test1 and Test2

Comment: if you email the scripts to sirow08@gmail.com. Then I can sort it out.

Comment: This is an amazing script!  However, does it support tables with a Clustered PK? (It looks like not?)

Comment: Hi @tbone thanks for the compliment. It will only work if the tables have a PK/Clustered keys. Otherwise the Source and destination tables can't join to each other. Do you get an error or the tables not updating?

Comment: Its an excellent script..thank you.. but I m facing problem, every column is repeated twice in the Merge statement.

Comment: Hi I am new to SQL but I have similar requirment in one of the project, My question is what if the two tables are not in the same DB, can we pass db.schema.tablename in source and in target table names?

Comment: Hi dspl, when doing the insert into a #tablemapping use a UNION to retrieve the Primary keys from the other database.

Answer (score 0):

1) Firstly why do you need the INTERSECT?

2) Secondly nothing will be inserted into temp1, because you say WHERE
   TABLE_NAME = '@tablename'.  There will never be a table name @tablename.
   Change it to WHERE TABLE_NAME = '' + @tablename + ''

3)Also '+@concat+' needs to be '' + @concat + ''

4) I really think the merge statement will need to be in Dynamic SQL, for you to split the @concat columns.

Comment: thanks for the insights.. I dont think single or double quotes make a difference. Even with " +@concat+" I get the same error as before. Also,merge statement inside the while loop will be very slow.

Comment: you need two single quotes and not double. You currently saying that '+@concat+' is the string value but its a parameter.  I am not saying put it in the loop. But the issue will be when splitting the columns to do your insert.  It won't work.  Thats why you need Dynamic SQL

Comment: @mvissrer. same error even with 2 single quotes. Also even right now Merge is using Dynamic SQL..

Comment: ok kwl.  Give me a few minutes.  I need to go on my computer. working on a Mac now. Let the SQL guru do this for you ;-)

Comment: no rush as long as it gets done..thanks again..and now you have raised my hopes up..;)